# Can I take the driving license tests in the UK and then be allowed to drive in Belgium?

Tags: united-kingdom

I work and live in Belgium however I am Brazilian and I want to take a drivers license in a country that I can do the test in English. Can I take the driving license tests in the UK and then be allowed to drive in Belgium?

Comment: Probably not, but maybe you can take the test in English in Belgium?  In some countries this is possible.  There's anyway a rather limited vocabulary to understand during the test, I'd expect you can learn sufficient French for this purpose without too much difficulty...

Comment: I recently took the test in California. Although I took it in the default language, English, the knowledge test is available in many languages. See [languages](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/dl/dl_info#languages)

Comment: According to https://www.angloinfo.com/how-to/belgium/transport/driving-licences/driving-test and http://www.goca.be/fr/p/pc-interpretes you can have an accredited translator present during the Belgian theory test (it says nothing about the practical test)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only apply for or renew a UK driving licence if you are resident in the UK. Furthermore, the DVLA [requires proof of immigration status](https://www.gov.uk/id-for-driving-licence) when you apply for a driving licence, if you are not from the UK/EEA/Switzerland. Since you won't have this, it is impossible for you to get a provisional licence.

Answer (score 1):

> I...live in Belgium....  Can I take the driving license tests in the UK...?

No.  Like most jurisdictions, the UK grants driving licenses only to residents of the UK.  This is such a fundamental assumption that the government's public information pages do not mention it explicitly, but if you start the process to [apply for a provisional license](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence), you will see that you cannot enter addresses outside the UK.